# EnvInject Error using Jenkins evaluated Groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

We have a evaluated Groovy script in Jenkins below:-
;

But the build is failing with error [EnvInject] - [ERROR] - [EnvInject] - [ERROR] - Problems occurs on injecting env vars as a build wrap: null
17:04:06 Finished: FAILURE.
Also how can I call the variable from Jenkins shell script to get last successful build date. -Thanks

```
def env = System.getenv()
def item = Jenkins.instance.getItem("")
 def  f=item.getLastFailedBuild()

 println f.getTime()

 def  ff=env['item.getLastSuccessfulBuild()]
  println ff.getTime().format("YYYY-MMM-dd HH:MM:SS")
  println ff.getTime().format("dd-MM-yyyy")

  def pa = new ParametersAction([new          StringParameterValue('PARAMETER_NAME', ff)]);
```

Thread.currentThread().executable.addAction(pa) 
println 'Script finished! \n`env variable`

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is that on line 7 you have no closing quote here:

`def  ff=env['item.getLastSuccessfulBuild()]`

However, that is not the last of your issues:

- I don't think you want to use `ff = env['item.getLastSuccessfulBuild()]']` but rather just a simple `ff = item.getLastSuccessfulBuild()`
- You need to include the following import lines to be able to use the associated classes:

  `import jenkins.model.Jenkins
  import hudson.model.ParametersAction
  import hudson.model.StringParameterValue`
- The line `item = Jenkins.instance.getItem("Fastlane_Test")` doesn't work in my environment, even replacing "Fastlane_Test" with a job that exists.
  I've replaced it with `item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("Fastlane_Test")`.
- Also, for safety, you should test to ensure `item` isn't *null*
- Finally, have you missed the `Thread.currentThread().executable.addAction(pa)` line out for a reason? You need to use it to add the new parameter to the running environment.

The following code should hopefully be a reasonable starting point, however please note that I've removed the line `def env = System.getenv()` since *env* isn't used anywhere else in the code later:

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import hudson.model.ParametersAction
import hudson.model.StringParameterValue

def item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("Fastlane_Test")

if (item) {
    def  f=item.getLastFailedBuild()

    println f.getTime()

    def  ff=item.getLastSuccessfulBuild()
    println ff.getTime().format("YYYY-MMM-dd HH:MM:SS")
    println ff.getTime().format("dd-MM-yyyy")

    def pa = new ParametersAction([new StringParameterValue("LAST_GOOD", ff.getTime().toString())])
    Thread.currentThread().executable.addAction(pa)
}
```

Hope you find this of assistance, although I see it's been a while since you posted the question.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Nick!!

I added the below "execute system groovyscript" as part of Jenkins job and it worked:
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

`.      def item = Jenkins.instance.getItem("Job")

```
def  ff=item.getLastSuccessfulBuild()
println ff.getTime().format("yyyy-MM-dd")
def temp = ff.getTime().format("yyyy-MM-dd")
import hudson.model.*
def build = Thread.currentThread().executable
def pa = new ParametersAction([
new StringParameterValue("LAST_BUILD_DATE",temp)
])
 build.addAction(pa)`
```